# Widget for retrieving the timeline of a user with Twitter4j, OAuth on Android

Tags: android, oauth, widget, twitter4j

I see the sample codes and walkthroughs on how to register your application, get the pin/uid and retrieve the access token and use it in the OnNewIntent method.

How can I do this OAuth authentication for a widget instead of an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start an Activity and start the Oauth flow from there.

You can use [setOnClickPendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to start an Activity if the user clicks on a part of the Widget, or use a Configuration Activity to have the user authenticate himself the moment the widget is placed on the homescreen.

Comment: I used a separate activity as you suggested. I also tried the configuration activity but i couldnT get it working. For the authentication I launch the browser and as far as I remember now, I get back in the activity with the activity callback url and parse the oauth result OnNewIntent (?). And i think this event is not available for the configuration activity.. But anyway, like i said, a separate activity did the trick..